# Unable to use wscat to connect to an ActionCable WebSocket on Ruby on Rails 5 Beta

Tags: websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I ran the ActionCable chat room sample that ships with Rails 5 Beta. The web app ran fine with data flowing up and down the WebSocket.

However, when I tried to connect to the WebSocket directly using `wscat` from the command line I got a connection error.

The `wscat` connection attempt:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:3000/cable
```

The error response:

```
error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

At first, I assumed Rails forgery protection prohibited the connection. So I added the following to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

However, I experienced the same connection error.

I tried using the `wsd` command line util to connect to the ActionCable WebSocket. `wsd` was worse, it crashed with a kernel panic.

I also tested both `wscat` and `wsd` with other WebSockets, including the WebSocket Echo Test http://www.websocket.org/echo.html, and they worked fine.

I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: double check actioncable is mounted in-process via `routes` or if its a standalone puma server via `bin/cable` in which case, its probably port 28080 iirc

Comment: @tw-airball thx for the comment. my routes files includes `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`. I tried `wscat -c ws://localhost:28080/cable` but see same error `error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I can connect fine using a telnet session i.e. `telnet localhost 3000` and do a manual websocket upgrade, yet `wscat -c ws://localhost:3000` fails with `error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000` every time.  Nothing in the Rails logs as if it really never received the request

Comment: The only way I could get this to work btw. was to bind Rails to host `0.0.0.0` i.e. `rails server -b 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

1) Spin up ActionCable via standalone server. (*this step needs verifying, but since ActionCable docs are still murky at the moment I will just layout the steps I did to make this work*).

Running `bin/cable` on `rails 5.0.0beta1` should fire up puma on port 28080.

(protip: make sure you don't have other conflicting puma processes running on config/puma.rb as puma will default load. You'll remember this and thank me later when you try to deploy rails app)

2) `ActionCable::Connection::Base` handles all incoming connections and decides how to identify users (e.g. `current_user`) or to reject unauthorized connections.

From the actioncable examples (https://github.com/rails/actioncable-examples) this is defined by cookie in `/app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb`.

Websocket connections from `wscat` will be rejected without pass authentication. You'll need to tweak this to fit your needs.

ActionCable still has alot of other "surprises". I hope to make update this post and/or make blog post documenting my experiences getting an iOS client to talk to ActionCable.

Good luck!

Comment: Were you able to get your iOS app talk to ActionCable? Can you share your experience?

Comment: @Griever yes we have an app in production(!), to establish socket I used SocketRocket. You need to send messages for subscribe channel manually.

Comment: Awesome! A blog post would be great.